# React-native: TextInput getting overlapped to it's parent view when app comes foreground

Tags: gesture-recognition, react-native-reanimated, react-native-textinput

I am facing one problem regarding my textInput.My textInput is going out of the parent view when my app comes in foreground from background. This is happening very frequently.

This happens when I have multiple lines inside textInput before sending app to background.

here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Here is the code**:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {useState,useRef} from 'react';
    import {View, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, Platform} from 'react-native';
    import GestureRecognizer, {swipeDirections} from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
    
    export default function ListItem() {
    
      const [textInputHeight, setTextInputHeight] = useState(36);
      const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Text');
      const height = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
      const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
      const componentHeight = 300;
      const parentContainerExpandedHeight =
        Platform.OS === "ios"
          ? (componentHeight) + textInputHeight - 45
          : (componentHeight) + textInputHeight - 15;
      const maxTextLengthWhenExpanded = 1000;
      const maxTextLengthWhenCollapsed = 250;

useEffect(() => {
    if (isKeyboardVisible) {
      if (isExpanded) {
        setIsExpanded(false);
        Animated.timing(height, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 200,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      }
    } else {
      if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.blur();
      }
      if (isExpanded) {
        setIsExpanded(false);
        Animated.timing(height, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 200,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      }
    }
  }, [isKeyboardVisible]);
    
      const onSwipeUp = () => {
        setIsExpanded(true);
        Animated.timing(height, {
          toValue: parentContainerExpandedHeight,
          duration: 400,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      };
    
      const onSwipeDown = () => {
        setIsExpanded(false);
        Animated.timing(height, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 400,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      };
      const getTextLayoutSize = (event: any) => {
        setTextInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
      };
    
    
      return (
       <GestureRecognizer onSwipeUp={() => onSwipeUp()} onSwipeDown={() => onSwipeDown()}>
          <View style={styles.parentContainer}>
            <View style={styles.handlebar} />
    
          <Animated.View style={[styles.childContainer, { minHeight: height }]}>
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <View style={styles.textImageWrapper}>
                  <ScrollView bounces={false}>
                   <TextInput
                          onLayout={getTextLayoutSize}
                          value={text}
                          onChangeText={onChangeText}
                          placeholder={'placeholder'}
                          placeholderTextColor="gray"
                          multiline
                          textAlignVertical="top"
                          style={{
                            textAlignVertical: 'top',
                            marginBottom: 10,
                          }}
                           maxLength={isExpanded ? maxTextLengthWhenExpanded : maxTextLengthWhenCollapsed
                      }
                        />
                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
              </View>
                 <View style={styles.container}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.submitButton}>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {}}
                    style={styles.submitButton}
                  >
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
        </GestureRecognizer>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      parentContainer: {
          minHeight: 120,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
          borderTopRightRadius: 8,
          justifyContent: "center",
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          paddingTop: 4,
        },
     handlebar: {
          width: 47,
          height: 4,
          borderRadius: 10,
          marginBottom: 8,
          alignSelf: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#808080",
        },
        childContainer: {
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          borderTopLeftRadius: 4,
          borderTopRightRadius: 4,
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 4,
          borderBottomRightRadius: 4,
          borderColor: "#808080",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderLeftWidth: 1,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          padding: 8,
        },
        textImageWrapper: {
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          paddingBottom: 10,
        },
         container: {
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        },
         submitButton: {
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          backgroundColor: "#808080",
          borderRadius: 100,
        }
    });
```